# The default value type does not match the type of the property

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have this class

```
public class Tooth
{
    public string Id {get;set;}
}
```

And this custrom control

```
public partial class ToothUI : UserControl
{
    public ToothUI()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Tooth Tooth
    {
        get { return (Tooth)GetValue(ToothProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ToothProperty, value);
            NombrePieza.Text =   value.Id.Replace("_",String.Empty);
        }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ToothProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Tooth", typeof(Tooth), typeof(ToothUI), new PropertyMetadata(0)); 

}
```

My problem is after Add **Tooth dependency property**, this error happen

**The default value type does not match the type of the property**

What exactly this error mean? What is the current way to set this `DP`

Answer (score 187, accepted):

`Default value` for `DP` does not match your type.

Change

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ToothProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Tooth", typeof(Tooth), typeof(ToothUI),
                                         new PropertyMetadata(0));
```

to

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ToothProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Tooth", typeof(Tooth), typeof(ToothUI),
                                      new PropertyMetadata(default(Tooth)));
```

Or simply omit setting default value for your DP:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ToothProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Tooth", typeof(Tooth), typeof(ToothUI));
```

Answer (score 6):

I came here for the title of the question but my type was a decimal default value and i solved with this 0.0M https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx