# WPF Dependency Property Error

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to define a dependency property like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DependencyPropertyName= DependencyProperty.Register("DepName", typeof(EnumName), typeof(MyWindow1), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("FrameWorkProperty", FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, Target));

private static void Target(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
{
    //some logic here
}

public EnumName DepName
{
    get { return (EnumName)GetValue(DependencyPropertyName); }
    set { SetValue(DependencyPropertyName, value); }
}
```

And i get this error, and dont understand why:

```
{"Default value type does not match type of property 'DepName'."}
```

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20398751/the-default-value-type-does-not-match-the-type-of-the-property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value type (`String`) of your Dependency Property does not match the Type of your property DepName (`EnumName`).

Change the default type in your dependency property and it should work.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DependencyPropertyName= DependencyProperty.Register(
    "DepName", 
    typeof(EnumName), 
    typeof(MyWindow1), 
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
        EnumName.SomeValue, // this is the defalt value
        FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, 
        Target));
```

Comment: Thank you for help, i don't know how i miss that :(

Comment: It's easy to go blind on your own code from time to time. All you need is to get away from your code a bit and get back with fresh eyes. Lunch usually does the trick for me ;)

Comment: Please note also that there are naming conventions for dependency property identifier fields. Yours should be called `DepNameProperty` instead of `DependencyPropertyName`. Please see the *Dependency Property Name Conventions* section in [Checklist for Defining a Dependency Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358.aspx#checklist) on MSDN.

Comment: That was just an example :)